# Does the Komar mass density act like a four density?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry

The Komar mass is a means of measuring gravitational mass in spacetime. Via Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komar_mass) it is stated as (for a stationary metric):

$$m=\int\rho d\mathrm{vol}=\intop\sqrt{g_{00}}(2T_{\mu\nu}-Tg_{\mu\nu})e^{\mu}e^{\nu}d\mathrm{vol}$$

where $T_{\mu\nu}$
  is the stress energy tensor, $g_{\mu\nu}$
  is the stress energy tensor, $e^{\mu}$
  is a unit time-like vector and $d\mathrm{vol}$
  is the three-volume form. Considering only orientable metrics, we can write:

$$d\mathrm{vol}=\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}g_{33}}e^{1}\wedge e^{2}\wedge e^{3}$$

Where, for simplicity we've considered a diagonalized metric. When we apply this to the above:

$$m=\intop\sqrt{g_{00}}(2T_{\mu\nu}-Tg_{\mu\nu})e^{\mu}e^{\nu}\sqrt{g_{11}g_{22}g_{33}}e^{1}\wedge e^{2}\wedge e^{3}$$

$$=\int(2T_{\mu\nu}-Tg_{\mu\nu})e^{\nu}\sqrt{g}d^{4}x$$

Which now appears as a full spacetime integral. Is this correct? I may have messed something simple up (such as a contraction somewhere), even then a variation of this appears valid. Tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komar mass is only well defined, i.e. Invariant, in a stationary spacetime, i.e., one admitting a timelike Killing vector. Your derivation seems to be good only for a static spacetime, i.e., no rotations, so a Kerr metric for instance would not be admitted. Not only that, you seemed to assume a diagonalized metric also in the space coordinates, not sure if that constrains it further (it may not, not sure).

The Wikipedia reference does show an invariant version of the mass formula for only stationary (and no other assumption) spacetime.

I'd not not know if your derivation, once you got to an invariant formation by assuming lots of zeros, is still right for a general stationary spacetime. you could assume more zeros, like T = 0, and that would certainly not prove the equation was right then In general

Comment: Thank you. I'm pursuing a line of thought that: $$\rho^{2}=T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}
 $$ Functions as an effective gravitational mass density, and it's naturally invariant. For that expression, there should be no static limitations. I was seeing how similar it is to the Komar mass.

Comment: Sorry, the above is factored such that $$\rho=e^{\nu}T_{\nu}^{\mu}e_{\mu}$$ which is not the same as the trace
BTW: Due to it's symmetric nature, the metric is always diagonalizable

Comment: Having a timelike Killing vector I don't think means that symmetric. If rotation it has to have some cross term I think

Comment: "Mathematically, spacetime is represented by a 4-dimensional differentiable manifold M and the metric is given as a covariant, second-order, symmetric tensor on M, conventionally denoted by g" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity) That's Wikipedia, but every text book I've ever read said the metric is symmetric, unless you leave relativity and start playing with nonzero torsions.

Comment: Sure, the metric is symmetric in that sense. But that does NOT mean you can diagonize it. Symmetries in general relativity space times (yes, without torsion) will give you certain conditions, like a timelike symmetry implies you can find a coordinate system where the metric is independent of time. A rotating otherwise symmetric body will have, as the vacuum metric outside, the Kerr metric. It has components like g sub t sub phi. That is the same as g sub phi sub t because there is no torsion. But it is not diagonal. That is what having cross terms means, not that those are not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Admittedly I'm new to this, I thought without a loss of generality (on the part of the space time) one could always choose a coordinate system in which the metric is diagonal.

Comment: One more information point. See other definitions of mass in GR, it's always had to be for timelike symmetries, or asymptotically flat or conformally flat. Papers by Sachs, Penrose, the ADM mass, and of course Komar.

Comment: Thanks, I found a paper on just what you were saying http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1600.pdf ill take that answer, but I sounds like you applied what I was talking about to a situation where the komar mass would never be applicable in the first place. Even in a non conformally flat space time, isn't there still a conservation when you look at total gravitational and mass energies together? Landau Lifshitz seem to have thought so, but like I said, just learning these things. Thanks again

Comment: Landau Lifshitz do indeed have that, but it is not a tensor, it is a pseudo-tensor (meaning it looks tensor like but it does not transfer like one). It is not covariant and then the conserved quantities are different in different coordinate systems. There is a big history in all this, and it's accepted fact. Note that for instance there are many useful approximations - for instance, the grav waves from the merging black holes carried away 3 solar masses of energy. We can talk that way because we assumed that that far away from those black holes we at earth are essentially asymptotically flat

Comment: I understood that while the pseudotensor varies under coordinate transformations the integrals of it do yield properly conserved quantities. Classical theory of fields landau lifshitz towards the end of the book

Comment: I'll look it up and respond.

Comment: ah! found it: Classical theory of fields 3rd edition 306-307

Comment: I have 2nd ed. Pp306-307 is about Petrov. I do see the pseudo tensor in what he called section 100. He explains why the vanishing of the covariant derivative does not lead to any conservation law. And says it is grav plus matter energy that is conserved. He then gets what he calls eq 100.9 where the sum of the grav pseudo tensor and matter energy tensor is 0 when integrated. Integrating over all spacetime gives conservation ONLY for asymptotically flat spacetime, he says when the space tends to constant Galilean. Cosmological spacetimes are not asymptotically flat, there's expansion at inf.

Comment: I appreciate that.  It seems improper exclude the background metric. What I mean is for a cosmological (expanding) space, your saying we have a changing total energy  for a body + it's gravitational field, and also a background metric with a changing energy (which in reality is the sum gravitational effects of all sources). It seems natural that the two are conserved together. For isotropic models it's certainly true: https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10952/makefile.pdf?sequence=1inly adding perturbations shouldn't affect this result. Like I said I'm learning though.

Comment: In this thesis she very thoroughly covers the flat case (leading up to 2.128), and for general curvature (leading up to just after 3.59). Worth noting is that she was arguing against the zero energy universe for the critically closed and open universes. I suppose what I'm trying to say is that there is a global conservation and there should be a method to convert this to a komar quantity for a local body (or maybe easier but less general would be  generalizing komar mass to conformal killing vectors)

Comment: looks like we can both be right haha! I don't side with Sean though in his convention choice http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/

Comment: It's all words. Or interpretation. What is not is that Komar mass and all the other masses or energies defined have not been invariantly defined in arbitrary spacetimes. And that the rules that come from the math seem to, as Landau said, match the physics in just the right way. And BTW, Sean Carroll writes a lot of words.